# Update table field value to null programmatically

Tags: java, mysql, sql

It is well known that how to set the field value to null by a simple query like -

```
UPDATE your_table
SET    your_column = NULL
WHERE  id = 1;
```

But pro-grammatically, which one is correct way to update the field value to null -

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE  your_table SET your_column='" + null + "WHERE id='" + myid + "'");
```

OR

```
db.execSQL("UPDATE  your_table SET your_column= NULL WHERE id='" + myid + "'");
```

Thanks

Comment: Is your query vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: yes it is. So what's the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with [**PreparedStatement**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

```
String query="UPDATE  your_table SET your_column= ? WHERE id=?");
PreparedStatement stmnt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
if(colyouAretryingtopass == null){]
  stmnt.setNull(1, Types.VARCHAR);
}
```

Comment: One more question - in your `if` condition you used `colyouAretryingtopass`. Isn't it the `your_column` to be checked for null and return if it's already null?

Comment: yepp, its the value you are trying to pass to your column from java. `colyouAretryingtopass == youColumnValue` :)

Comment: So its-  `if(your_column == null) return else stmt.setNull(1, Types.VARCHAR)`. Looks reasonable.

Comment: @SaurabhJain you obviously have to replace the type with your type. if your column is of type int, then Types.INT.Check the Types API for all the supported sql Types. :)

Comment: ok, I think the benefit of this code is also that it will not execute if the field is already null.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way is to use bind variables, depending on the framework you are using this is done in different ways.

You query should be something like follows;

```
String query = "UPDATE your_table SET your_column = null WHERE id = ?";
executeQuery(query, id);
```

Where `executeQuery(String query, Object... args)` is the the DB access method of your choice.

If you don't use bind variables you are;

a) Vunerable to SQL injection.
b) Losing performance by not utilising query cache on the database.

Comment: Good idea to use the separate common method each time you execute query. Thanks!